# How do I block an app from ever installing in Android 12?

Tags: installation, uninstallation, android-12

There is one notorious app. That gets installed every now and then. How do I stop it from happening in Android 12. Is there a way to block it from ever installing from google play store?

Comment: If an app that uses the same packageName but a different signature app installation should be blocked. You can try to build a simple "hello world app" using the same packageName as the app you want to block or you could try to edit an existing app of small size you decompile with [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), change the packageName in AndroidManifest.xml recompile it, sign it using a generated custom signature key and the install it on your phone.

Answer (score -2):

Turn automatic update off in settings

Comment: This may stop updating *existing* app, but doesn't prevent installing the app if it's not yet installed (e.g. after uninstallation).